# How to build an "_2.10.0" artifact with sbt?

Tags: sbt, scala-2.10

I am building a project with sbt 0.12.2 and scala 2.10.0 (with scalaVersion := "2.10.0" in the build.sbt file). The artifacts built are named xxx_2.10-xxx.jar, with the tailing ".0" in the original version string truncated. What I want is something like xxx_2.10.0-xxx.jar. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: This is the new standard cross versioning scheme, since Scala 2.10.x is binary compatible.  Can you explain why you want 2.10.0?

Comment: I am trying to build the n8han/giter8 project on github with scala-2.10. Giter8 is launched by sbt-launcher, which will download approriate dependency libraries according to the scala version attribute specified in a configuration file. The problem is, on the maven central repository, the scala-library and scala-compiler artifacts for scala 2.10 are actually named scala-library_2.10.0 and scala-compiler_2.10.0, but the giter8 artifact built with sbt is named giter8_2.10. So no matter "2.10" or "2.10.0" is configured, there are unresolvable dependencies.

Comment: scala-library and scala-compiler are not cross-versioned, so I doubt they look like scala-library_2.10.0.  I'd update the question with the full problem- the relevant configuration files and the error message.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I made a mistake about the artifact name of scala-library and scala-compiler - the "_" should be replaced with "-". The url for the artifact of scala 2.10 is [http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0/scala-library-2.10.0.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0/scala-library-2.10.0.jar). There is not something like [http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10/scala-library-2.10.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10/scala-library-2.10.jar). So the problem is still there.